# Error in Tests: The 'async' operator lacks await operator

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I have a unit test to check `null` parameter. The test method is something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Test_NullParam()
{
    Mock<IAuth> mockAuth = new Mock<IAuth>();
    Task<AuthenticationResult> mockResult = null;

    await Assert.ThrowsExceptionAsync<ArgumentNullException>(async () =>
    {
        mockAuth
          .Setup(x => x.Authenticate(null, param2, param3, param4))
          .Returns(mockResult);
    });
}
```

It is showing error under `(async ()`.

The error is:

> The async lacks await operator

`mockResult` showing:

> Result is always null

** Edited **

Class code below:

```
  public async Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string param1, string param2, string param3, string param4)
    {
        try
        {
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(param1);
            if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any()) authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);
            var authResult = await
            authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(param2, param3, new Uri(param4), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, false));
            return authResult;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Nkosi Authenticate method takes four parameters and it performs AD authentication in Azure.

I want to individually check if any of the parameter is null.

Comment: Ok lets break this down. I assumed `IAuth` is being injected as a dependency into some class, No? You would typically mock the desired behavior of the dependency in order to test a specific target class. Or are you trying to test the actual implementation of a derived class of that interface?

Comment: @Nkosi I want to test only one method named: Authenticate. This method is declared in IAuth. There is one Authenticator class which implements this interface. Ideally I want to write Mock test using IAuth.

Comment: @Nkosi code added. Updated original post

Comment: Making progress. What do you hope to test in that method? I get the impression that you are testing the wrong thing. You should be testing the method that is actually using the `IAuth`. Then mocking `IAuth` would make sense

Comment: @Nkosi Yes, I want to check the method for null parameters and method not implemented. Any other tests please suggest. Illustrate how to test the method.

Comment: https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/06/18/mocking-adal-for-unit-tests/

Comment: @Nkosi It is using AuthenticationContext. Can something simple be added in my code? Adding AuthenticationContext will be an additional work.

Comment: You already have `AuthenticationContext` in your code so I do not understand your last statement

Comment: @Nkosi Yes correct. I thought it is a different class. That sample does does not show AuthenticationResultWrapper and IAuthenticationResultWrapper.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting the error because you aren't performing an `await` statement in the lambda you've passed to `ThrowsExceptionAsync`.

More importantly, you appear to be performing your mocking setup within the lambda instead of actually executing the method that you are testing.  You should move your mocking outside of the lambda, and execute the method you are testing within the lambda like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Test_NullParam()
{
    // create all of your mocks that are required to run this test
    Mock<IAuth> mockAuth = new Mock<IAuth>();
    Task<AuthenticationResult> mockResult = null;
    mockAuth
        .Setup(x => x.Authenticate(null, param2, param3, param4))
        .Returns(mockResult);

    // you actually need to create the concrete type you want to test
    // you shouldn't make a unit test that just uses mocks!

    // construct the concrete type and pass in any mocks that the 
    // object requires
    var objectToTest = new MyRealObject(mockAuth.Object);

    await Assert.ThrowsExceptionAsync<ArgumentNullException>(async () =>
    {
        // actually execute the real method here, the assertion
        // is expecting this method to throw an exception, and will
        // only pass if an exception is thrown
        await objectToTest.MyMethodAsync();
    });
}
```

Note that if the method you are testing isn't asynchronous, you should change your unit test to not be async, and use `Assert.ThrowsException` instead.

**Edit:**

In response to your comment about mocking the `Task`, if you want to mock a `Task` that returns a `null` `AuthenticationResult`, you should do the following:

```
// declare the result
AuthenticationResult mockResult = null;

// set up the authenticate method to return the task
mockAuth
    .Setup(x => x.Authenticate(null, param2, param3, param4))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(mockResult));
```

The important part here is `Task.FromResult`.  This will give you an actual `Task`, that will return `null` when awaited, instead of the `Task` being `null` itself.

If you want to use an `AuthenticationResult` that isn't null, you are going to run into problems, due to the `AuthenticationResult` class having no public constructors, and no way of getting one, other than actually running a real Authenticate request.  Out of the box, `AuthenticationResult` isn't mockable, which is why @Nkosi has provided a link to an article about [using wrapper classes to make it mockable](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/06/18/mocking-adal-for-unit-tests/).

**Edit 2**

It seems the linked blog post is not complete, as it does not include all the wrapper types required, so I decided to make them myself so this answer could be complete.

Due to the character limit constraints on StackOverflow answers, I've had to put the files on Github here: https://github.com/DoctaJonez/DoctorJones.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/tree/master

Once you've added these classes and interfaces, you'll be able to do the following:

```
// you can now mock authentication results, and set them up to 
// emulate whatever conditions you like
var mockResult = new Mock<IAuthenticationResultWrapper>();

// you'll need to use the IAuthenticationContextWrapper, so all the
// method signatures know about our new IAuthenticationResultWrapper
var mockAuth = new Mock<IAuthenticationContextWrapper>();

// here's how we mock the IAuthenticationContextWrapper to return our
// mocked IAuthenticationResultWrapper
mockAuth.Setup(x => x.Authenticate(null, param2, param3, param4))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(mockResult.Object));
```

Comment: In the end I believe this is what the OP would need. But since they were not clarifying/knowing what it is they were doing they couldn't explain the actual problem and I did not want to guess.

Comment: I understand, it can be risky guessing as to what the OP is asking, but I wanted to be helpful if possible, even if I slightly missed the point of the OP, it can still prove useful.

Comment: @DoctorJones It is showing error "Cannot convert from Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationResult to System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationResult>", in mockResult in this line: mockAuth
        .Setup(x => x.Authenticate(null, param2, param3, param4))
        .Returns(mockResult);

Comment: @DoctorJones On changing to Task<AuthenticationResult> mockResult = null, it is showing warning: mockResult is always null in the above mentioned (previous comment) code line.

Comment: Hi @RKh, I have updated to answer your problem with the task result

Comment: @DoctorJones The link provided by Nkosi does not have code for AuthenticationResult wrapper class.

Comment: @RKh, I've edited the answer to include the implementation of all wrapper classes and interfaces that you'll need (there are 4 in total).  I've linked to them on Github, because posting them directly inline was not possible due to size constraints.